PrimeNg Tree : Make some droppoints not droppable when drag start
I have to define a specific DragDrop behavior in my p-tree component.
I have a tree like this :
- Item 1
--- Item 2
----- Folder 1
------- Item 3
--------- Folder 2
----- Folder 3
------- Item 4
--- Folder 4
----- Item 5

We can reorganize the tree but when a node is moved, its parent item must stay the same, folders does not count. For example :

I can move Item 3 inside Item 2 or inside Folder 3 (its parent item is still Item 2)
I can't move Item 3 inside Item 4 or inside Item 1
I can move Folder 3 inside Folder 1
I can't move Folder 3 inside Item 3 or Folder 2 (its parent will become Item 3)

To implement this behavior, i change node property 'droppable' when the drag starts (with TreeDragDropService.dragStart$) and it works fine: when i try to drop a node inside another, it's enabled/disabled correctly. But it does not work when i try to drop a node aside another.
Example :
 - Item 1
 --- Item 2
 ----- Folder 1
 ------- Item 3
 --------- Folder 2
 ----- Folder 3
 <-- Drop is enabled here, i can't disable
 ------- Item 4 <-- Drop is correctly disabled here
 --- Folder 4
 ----- Item 5 <-- Drag this node

Has anyone encountered this issue before?
I tried to cancel the drop afterwards using Tree.prototype.allowDrop, but there is an issue with identifying the nodes :
- Item 1
--- Item 2
<-- When i drop here, dropNode is Folder 1 instead of Item 2
----- Folder 1 <-- When i drop here, as expected dropNode is Folder 1
------- Item 3
--------- Folder 2
----- Folder 3
------- Item 4
--- Folder 4
----- Item 5

Due to this confusion, I can't distinguish a valid drop from an invalid drop.
